# Can I pass a format statement to a subroutine in Fortran?

Tags: file-io, fortran, fortran90

I'd like to be able to pass a 'format' into a Fortran subroutine. Take this example:

```
        write(6,1002) M1    
1002    format(A, "M1, Mach number at boundary layer edge", f8.3)
```

For reasons too involved to go into here it would be useful to have a generic function to which I send a variable with a format statement that would be used to write out.  I can't figure out a way of doing this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really pass a format statement to a subroutine.  But you can pass a format string, something like:

```
fmtstr = '(A, "M1, Mach number at boundary layer edge", f8.3)'
...
call mysub(args, fmtstr)
```

then

```
subroutine mysub(args, fmtstr)
    ...
    character(*), intent(in) :: fmtstr
    ...
    write(*,fmtstr) M1
end subroutine
```

Some might argue that format strings are the best modern way to handle formats in all circumstances and have retired their use of format statements entirely.

Comment: Careful with missing parentheses :)

Answer (score 1):

Forget FORMAT statements, use *format strings*

```
   string = '(A, "M1, Mach number at boundary layer edge", f8.3)'
   write(*,string) M1
```

You can pass strings easily to a subroutine.

Format statements are just obsolete and awkward to work with.

Also, do not use unit number `6`, but `*`, that is much more portable.